# Delete ID and delete Li tag with another ID

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to delete ID from photos DB, but in li tags i have Categories number and i have set it to class.
Code is following:

```
$().ready(function() {
  $(".delete").on("click",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ID = encodeURI($(this).attr("id"));
        var CAT = $(".photos li").attr("class");
        alert(CAT);
    });
});
<ul class="photos">
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo "<li class='c".$data['cat_id']."'><a href='#' class='delete' id='".$data['id']."'>".$data['photo_name']."</a></li>";
 }
```

I'm using multiple categories but when i click delete result is **c1**

Comment: what does **`when i click delete result is c1`** mean ? What is **`c1`** and how does it help us with your issue?

Comment: You are alerting the category class by `alert(CAT)` and not the ID.

Comment: yes i alerting CAT because ID is fine i need category, charlietfl when i want to delete some pic from db beforeSend: function() { $(".c"+CAT).slideToggle('slow', function() {$(this).remove();}); }

Comment: I don't know why show me only category 1 because i'm using multiple categories !

Comment: Please show the html, jQuery works on the html your php is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to delete the ID of the photo instead of the category id, why even write code for it?  The following should alert you to the ID of that photo delete link you clicked on.  It appears that having `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of the function prevents anything else from executing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function(event) {
        var ID = encodeURI($(this).attr("id"));
        var CAT = $(this).closest("li").attr("class");
        alert(ID + " " + CAT);
        e.preventDefault();     
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cq49P/5/

Comment: So you need both?  It doesn't seem very clear in your description.

Comment: First sorry for bad english, I have 3 photos from 3 categories. This is a TOP PHOTOS so i have created function for replace it now i'm trying to delete photo from selected category. I hope you can understand me now.

Comment: Sorry, didn't include my modification for .parent()

Comment: strange if i use this code show me undefined  echo "<li class='c".$data['cat_id']."'><img class='img-border' src='../photos/".$data['photo_name']."' width='190' height='140' />";
echo "<span style='position:absolute; top:-12px; right:-12px; width:30px; height:30px;'><a href='#' class='delete' id='".$data['id']."'><img src='../fancybox/fancy_close.png' /></a></span>";
echo "<span style='position:absolute; top:5px; left:0; width:auto; height:auto; padding:5px;'>".$data['cat_name']."</span></li>";

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  Can you paste the HTML generated by your PHP script into that JSFiddle page?

Comment: It works with the current version of jQuery on that JSFiddle page.

Comment: Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Cat_id is a `class` not an `Id`. Use [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). TO remove the class.

So just that I get your problem... You write the id in a class name, prefex it with c and then all elements are like: c1, c2..... and you want to get the number of c.

First of all: Use the data-attribute on the element. Example:

```
echo "<li class='' data-cat_id=".$data['cat_id']."'><a href='#' class='delete' id='".$data['id']."'>
```

(not a php expert, but your result html should look like this: `<li class='' data-cat_id="1"....`
This is the way I suggest you should use.

If you really really have to do it with classes
You can do it like this:

```
$(function($) {
    var CAT = $("li").each(function() {
        var CAT = this.className.split(' ');
        var regex = /^c[0-9]*$/;
        $.each(CAT, function(){
            if(this.match(regex )){
                alert(this.split('c')[1]);
            }
        });
    });      

});
​[Fiddler][2].
```

Comment: var CAT = $(".photos li").attr("class"); i need ID from category only show me c1